# Page Layout - How to

Tags: page-layout

How do I find a live ticket/case with a particular page layout? 
 -I know I can view a page layout as "X-User" but I want to login as X-user and see a live version of that particular page layout because "view as X-member" doesn't allow you to see if certain fields are editable for that user.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of tools that you can apply here.

- One is to [Login As](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=logging_in_as_another_user.htm&type=5) the other user. You'll need the appropriate permissions to do so (see the linked documentation), but once you perform a Login As, you view your live Salesforce as that user. Their permissions and visibility settings are applied as you browse, up to the point where you log out as them and assume your normal user identity and permissions again.
- Another is the [View Field Accessibility](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=checking_field_accessibility_for_a_particular_field.htm&type=5) tool. You can access this button within the detail page of any field in Setup. It allows you to view a matrix that shows the visibility and editability of a single field for every combination of profile and record type in your org. Once you're viewing the matrix, mouse over any entry to see details of *why* that profile can or cannot view/edit the field.

It is worth noting that the Salesforce security and visibility architecture is **very complex**. There are many reasons why a user might be able to edit or not edit some specific record or field, including profile-level permissions like View All Data/Modify All Data, the permission to edit read-only fields, record-level sharing, and so forth.

It may be helpful to you to complete the [Data Security](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/data_security) module on Trailhead to get a feel for the basics of field/object/record level security mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks David. I covered all of those grounds and found the loophole.

For future reference though, when I'm working on a page, is there no way to find a working case that's utilizing that page layout? 
 -I just started a new job and they have 50+ page layouts... & when I'm editing a page, I want to see a live version of it and have no idea how to search for that.

Comment: No, there is no simple tool that I'm aware of to go from the page layout editor to a live record page for a record that is displayed using that page layout. Reports and list views can help, but you'd have to build them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there are multiple recordtypes and page layouts are there for Case object.

You can easily view the page layout of that user as follows:

1. Check the user's profile
2. Verify the recordtype to page layout assignment based on the profile.
3. Check the FLS for that profile.(as some of the fields might not visible in that user's profile)
4. Then view the page layout of the case.
5. Finally compare that page layout opening in a different browser upon logged in with the user and opening the record.

Comment: I didnt understand this answer